# Combining two pandas dataframes/tables of unequal lengths

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames of different lengths:

```
df1:                           df2:
  Column1  Column2             ColumnA ColumnG ColumnSG
0    ab1       bc1                ab1      A      AA
1    ab2       ab5                bc1      B      BB   
2    ab3       bc4                ab3      C      CC
3    ab4       ab5                ab1      D      DD
4    ab5       ab1                ab5      E      EE 
                                  bc4      F      FF    
                                  ab2      G      GG
                                  ab4      H      HH
```

I would like an output that looks something like this:

df1:

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIbtt.png)

What I tried so far?

```
for row in df1, df2:
   if df1[Column1] == df2[ColumnA]:
      df1[ColumnG1] = df2[ColumnG]
      df1[ColumnSG1] = df2[ColumnSG]
```

But, this gave me an error saying:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it merge twice:

```
(df1.merge(df2.rename(columns={"ColumnA":'Column1'}), on='Column1',how='left')
    .merge(df2.rename(columns={'ColumnA':'Column2'}), on='Column2',how='left',
           suffixes=['1','2'])
)
```

Output:

```
  Column1 Column2 ColumnG1 ColumnSG1 ColumnG2 ColumnSG2
0     ab1     bc1        A        AA        B        BB
1     ab1     bc1        D        DD        B        BB
2     ab2     ab5        G        GG        E        EE
3     ab3     bc4        C        CC        F        FF
4     ab4     ab5        H        HH        E        EE
5     ab5     ab1        E        EE        A        AA
6     ab5     ab1        E        EE        D        DD
```